I completed a transaction buying solana, but it didn’t show up in my wallet
I had recently made a wallet on phantom and purchased solana, i have the transaction history and proof of purchase but it is not showing up in my wallet

You purchase SOL not Solana (Solana is a network) but I get what you mean.  What's the tranaction ID?
